# How to uninstall opencv3.1?

Tags: uninstall, opencv

Long story short, the features in OpenCV3.1 does not work for me. I did uninstall the OpenCV3.1 with `sudo apt-get purge libopencv*` and install the OpenCV2.4.11 with [this](https://gist.github.com/dynamicguy/3d1fce8dae65e765f7c4), but after installing it, The `cv2.__version__`'s result is `'3.1.0'`!!

## Question:

How to uninstall the OpenCV3.1 and replace it with the 2.4.11 one?

---

#### Editions:

**dpkg -l | grep opencv:**

```
ii  opencv-data 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1 all development data for opencv
```

**whereis opencv**

```
opencv: /usr/share/opencv
```

**locate cv.py:**

```
/home/dariush/ardupilot/modules/mavlink/pymavlink/tools/python_array_test_recv.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv.pyc
```

Comment: How exactly did you install OpenCV3.1 in the first place?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I don't remember!! If I have to guess it would be `apt-get`.

Comment: Please check your command history with `history`.

Comment: It would just be good to know which package you selected to install. You've probably got dependencies from it still left or something.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Please [edit] your question to include the outputs of `dpkg -l | grep opencv` and `whereis opencv` and `locate cv.py` (these will help us figure out how you likely installed it).

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Ok I have figured it out... I downloaded the OpenCV source file and compiled/installed it, I download the OpenCV3.1 files again and execute the `cmake .. && sudo make uninstall` but the result is: `make: *** No rule to make target `uninstall'.  Stop.` any ideas?

Comment: @steeldriver done.

Comment: So then purging it with `apt-get` won't work because that's not how you installed it, you must have purged something else rather than what you compiled from source.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda agreed, then how can I fix this now?

Comment: File `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv.py` would normally be provided by the opencv python bindings package `python-opencv`, however that doesn't appear in your `dpkg` output either so likely was part of your source install. It *may* be sufficient to install `python-opencv` from the repository (OTOH it might refuse/complain about overwriting files that are outside of the package management system).

Answer (score 3):

Things that didn't work.

- `sudo apt-get purge libopencv-* python-data python-opencv`
- Uninstall the 2.4.11 and Installing the OpenCV3.1 from source then Uninstalled.

After I reinstall and uninstalled the 3.1 version I still can `import cv2` without any problem, from `cv2.__file__` I remove the `'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so'` file.

Then I installed the `2.4`version from source and `apt-get install python-opencv` the `cv2.__version__` is OK now.